# Trello @ notifications don't seem to work for me, not sure what is wrong

Tags: trello, notifications

Various users on our trello board are using the convention of @username to attempt to send me messages. But the convention does not work. I never receive a notification.

Is there some usage convention we need to consider as in should the reference appear after some other text in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of Trello having this feature, and it is not mentioned in [the Trello user guide](https://trello.com/guide).

I think that Trello just doesn't have this functionality. It's a nice idea, though: you could email it as a suggestion to: `feature-ideas@trello.com`

Having said that, in general Trello tries to minimise the amount of email it sends. So if you used the system soon after a change was made, you likely wouldn't get a notification anyway. See the recent [On Email Notifications](http://blog.trello.com/on-email-notifications/) blog for recent info on email in Trello.

Answer (score 1):

You could always mention someone by first name or last name (e.g. `@george` or `@rasch`).

Now that [the card for `@username` mentions](https://trello.com/card/board/mentions-using-usernames/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4ecbe10c4731c1000007726d) is live, you can mention them using `@username` as well.